# Cisco NCS - how to mass update AP settings

Tags: cisco, wifi, snmp

we have a NCS (Cisco Prime Network Control System) to monitor our wireless network.

To update AP names and location i have to search for the ap mac address in the web interface, and configure them one by one.

Is there a way to do this programmatically? That is, build a piece of software that reads a tab seperated file with AP mac-address, wanted name and location, that connects to the NCS and update this information?

I have programming experience, but I've never done anything with SNMP or similar.

What is the best approach here?

Comment: Nope. Due to Cisco's awesome logic and planning there is no such feature in NCS or any of their other monitoring products. I have been looking in the past and still looking now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me know if you find anything. I'm thinking about writing some javascript to search and autoupdate the AP configuration through the web interface.

Comment: Will probably be easier to write something, I would be interested to see how it work outs... :) good luck.

Comment: You can update AP names, Location, Primary, Secondary, Tertiary, etc.. info if you SSH into a wireless controller. Review the config/ap commands...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a function on the NCS to mass update AP configurations.

Go to

> Configure -> Access Points

, and in the drop down in the top right select

> Import AP Config

The import takes a comma seperated file (csv).

> Sample File Header: AP Name,Ethernet MAC,Location,Primary
>   Controller,Secondary Controller,Tertiary Controller
>
> ap-1, 00:1c:58:74:8c:22, sjc-14-a, controller-4404-1,
>   controller-4404-2, controller-4404-3 The CSV file can contain
>   following fields. AP Ethernet MAC Address is mandatory, Optional
>   fields are AP Name, Location, Primary Controller, Secondary Controller
>   and Tertiary Controller.  Optional fields can be empty. AP Config
>   Import will ignore empty optional field values. However, if Primary
>   Controller and Secondary Controller entries are empty then Unified AP
>   update is not done
>
> Ethernet MAC: AP Ethernet MAC Address AP Name:AP Name Location:AP
>   Location Primary Controller:Primary Controller Name Secondary
>   Controller:Secondary Controller Name Tertiary Controller:Tertiary
>   Controller Name

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

Yes, you can do this with the capabilites of `wget` or `curl` - both are capable of acting as HTML clients (of course, no Javascript), accepting cookies and the like.

But No, the time required to create such a script, identifying how you need to talk to the web interface may be longer than just doing the mouse monkey...

Comment: yeah, i've looked at it, but i've not completed the javascript code. We do however have about 3000 APs, so it takes quite some time do do it manually.

Comment: Hoozah, then it's definitively worth the effort. Good luck!